# Segment Airport-based Home Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns

I would like to segment my network up so that I can better lock down my kids as they are getting to the ages where I'll need to get them a computer.

I would prefer to use OpenDNS's filtering services on a router level, however I don't want to lock my wife and I down too much which is why I'm wondering about segmenting.

I currently have a Airport Extreme A/C, Airport Extreme (2011 model) and 2 current Airport Express'. We are a pretty well Mac-based household with 1 iMac, 2 MBP's, 3 iPad mini's, 2 iPhones and 2 ATV's.

I did some digging and found a tip about creating a separate pool for the kids devices where they use OpenDNS for their DNS and I could leave everything else untouched. I already lock them out of modifying the network settings on their devices, so them changing this shouldn't be much if an issue.

Here's a link to that article: http://joeywhelan.blogspot.com/2013/09/dns-jailed-network.html

Does anyone have any recommendations they could share or give me a pointer of what equipment I might need or whatnot? I'm wondering if I should use a Mac Mini as a home server and do the DHCP there or are there other devices? Any help is greatly appreciated!!